# puppet agent configuration issues with puppet opswork aws

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have created the puppet master using aws opsworks. I got a url to login and was able to login into it.

I have issues when I try to add a linux or windows host to the puppet master.
for linux I have used the command

```
curl -k https://puppet-new-7galokccdlftwt9r.us-east-1.opsworks-cm.io:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash
```

Tried to send sign request

```
puppet agent -t
Error: Could not request certificate: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: /puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca (method :get). Please see the server logs for details.
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

**On windows**

I installed puppet agent, modified puppet.conf and tried to sign the request. I got the same 403 forbidden errors.
I can see the machine is reachable via ip and fqdn, port 8140 is open from agent to master and master to agent.
I can see the certs generated in ssl folder of agent but do not see any requests on the master.

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: If the agent cannot certify against the CA, then almost certainly the bootstrap from the `curl` command failed too. Check the logs there to see what failed and why.

Comment: This has been resolved following the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647384/windows-puppet-agent-does-not-connect-to-the-awsopsworks-puppet-enterprise-maste?rq=1