# puppet Forbidden request /puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca

Tags: puppet, aws-opsworks, puppet-enterprise

I'm not able to make a puppet node join a master, i'm using puppet enterprise on AWS cloud.

Master

```
puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 2017.3.0.38
```

Node

```
# puppet agent --test
Error: Could not request certificate: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: /puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca (method :get). Please see the server logs for details.
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

obviously error message is related to permission on master side, when i check the log on the master i see

```
ERROR [qtp2147089302-255] [p.t.a.rules] Forbidden request: 10.0.10.224 access to /puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca (method :get) (authenticated: false) denied by rule 'puppetlabs certificate'.
```

but i checked that the new HOCON format for auth.conf is allowing un authenticated node to send CSR

```
{
            "allow-unauthenticated": "*",
            "match-request": {
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/puppet-ca/v1/certificate/",
                "query-params": {},
                "type": "path"
            },
            "name": "puppetlabs certificate",
            "sort-order": 500
        }
```

i checked also that pe-puppet-server.conf is not using the legacy auth.conf method

```
# (optional) Authorize access to Puppet master endpoints via rules specified
# in the legacy Puppet auth.conf file (if true or not specified) or via rules
# specified in the Puppet Server HOCON-formatted auth.conf (if false).
use-legacy-auth-conf: false
max-active-instances: 2
max-requests-per-instance: 0
environment-class-cache-enabled: true
```

please advise, the same error msg occurs on both windows and linux

Comment: Not sure but `"path": "/puppet-ca/v1/certificate/"` doesn't match the request `/puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca`

Answer (score 0):

i did reboot the entire server(ec2 instance) since reloading puppetserver didn't help ... i also did the auth change from the console, as structed here

[windows Puppet agent does not connect to the awsopsworks puppet Enterprise master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647384/windows-puppet-agent-does-not-connect-to-the-awsopsworks-puppet-enterprise-maste?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to setup my puppet nodes, but was using Vagrant instead of AWS.

The fix was to unset the following environment variables: `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to remove `server_list` from `puppet.conf`, cleanup CM cert and re-generate cert. In my case I have `autosign=true` so the process was:

1. Stop PE on CM:

```
systemctl stop puppet pxp-agent pe-puppetserver pe-puppetdb
```

2. Remove ssl dir

```
rm -fr /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
```

3. Cleanup cert from Primary:

```
puppetserver ca clean --certname='<CM>'
```

4. Run puppet agent on CM

```
puppet agent -t
```

Done.